# CheckBoxList unable to assign values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net project that I am working on. My CheckBoxList control is

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="p1" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="-1" RepeatColumns="4"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And my C# code is

```
private static CheckBoxList ReturningValues()
{
    CheckBoxList myList = new CheckBoxList();

    string list = "25 28 32 41";
    string[] values = list.Split(' ');

    foreach (var checkbox in values)
    {
        myList.Items.Add(checkbox);
    }

    return myList;
}
```

All I want to achieve is to assign the values from ReturningValues method to my p1 CheckboxList.

```
p1.SelectedValue = ReturningValues().ToString();
```

But when I assign return values, the CheckboxList is Empty. How would i make it work to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding values to the already existing CheckBoxList `p1`, but are creating a new one. I think you want to add checkboxes to `p1`. So do this

```
private void ReturningValues()
{
    string list = "25 28 32 41";
    string[] values = list.Split(' ');

    //loop the values in the array
    foreach (var checkbox in values)
    {
        p1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = checkbox, Value = checkbox });
    }

    //add items to p1
    p1.DataBind();
}
```

Or a shorter version is to bind an array directly as a DataSource.

```
int[] values = new int[] { 25, 28, 32, 41 };

p1.DataSource = values;
p1.DataBind();
```